# howto add entries in JSON array with velocity

Tags: velocity, xwiki

With velocity I declare my array like this:

```
#set ($MyArray={
  'Index1':{'Field1':'value1','field2':'value2'},
  'Index3':{'Field1':'A value','field2':'Another value'}
})
```

How can I add an "Index2" entrie by example:

```
'Index2':{'Field1':'A new value','field2':'Another new value'}"
```

or can I modify a value ('Index 1'.field2' by example)?

Thxs for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$MyArray is not an array variable but a map (Thxs to Marius):
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Then the answer is:

```
#set ($MyArray={
  'Index1':{'Field1':'value1','field2':'value2'},
  'Index3':{'Field1':'A value','field2':'Another value'}
})
$MyArray.getClass().getName()
* Original map
$jsontool.serialize($MyArray)
* I Modify the 'Index3' entrie:
#set ($discard=$MyArray.put('Index3',{'Field1':'A modified value','field2':'Another modified value'}))
$jsontool.serialize($MyArray)
* I add the 'Index2' entrie:
#set ($discard=$MyArray.put('Index2',{'Field1':'Addon value','field2':'Another addon value'}))
$jsontool.serialize($MyArray)
```